# Fallback to a default value on Kotlin Deserialization error

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I am using Kotlin Serialization to deserialize a JSON response from the network.

When there are errors during the deserialization, I would like to catch them and fallback to a default value (ideally `null`) for that node, keeping the rest of the successfully deserialized info. In other words, fail gracefully.

### Example

For example: I am deserializing some `User` info. Some of that info is really `important` -- if there's an error there it should fail the whole object. But some other info is `nonImportant` -- if there's an error there it should keep the `important` info and set `nonImportant = null`. Here would be a basic setup:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class User(
    val important: ImportantInfo,
    val nonImportant: NonImportantInfo? = null,
)

@Serializable
data class ImportantInfo(
    val userId: Int,
)

@Serializable
data class NonImportantInfo(
    val errorProneField: Boolean? = null,
)
```

And this is what I hope to get when deserializing these different users (note the type mismatch in case 2 and 3 that should provoke a deserialization error).

```kotlin
val json = Json

val validUser = json.decodeFromString<User>("""{
    "importantInfo": { "userId": 123 },
    "nonImportantInfo": { "errorProneField": true }
}""")
// Expectation:
// User(ImportantInfo(userId = 123), NonImportantInfo(errorProneField = true))


val partiallyInvalidUser = json.decodeFromString<User>("""{
    "importantInfo": { "userId": 123 },
    "nonImportantInfo": { "errorProneField": "this is not a boolean" }
}""")
// Expectation:
// User(ImportantInfo(userId = 123), NonImportantInfo(errorProneField = null))


val invalidUser = json.decodeFromString<User>("""{
    "importantInfo": { "userId": "this is not an int" },
    "nonImportantInfo": { "errorProneField": true }
}""")
// Expectation:
// An error is thrown by decodeFromString
```

### Approches I've tried

Of course I could achieve this by defining a custom KSerializer for `NonImportantInfo`. But I'm trying to do this in a generic way: in my example I have only 3 objects; in the real world I have 5 or 6 layers of nested objects and I'd like any of them to fallback to null if it fails to deserialize.

I could also achieve it by defining a wrapper class `Safe<T>` and a single custom deserializer for that (better!), but that would mean I need to use this wrapper everywhere in my response objects.

I'm hoping I can use the native Kotlin nullable types (`T?`), and define a single generic deserializer that works for all nullable types.

Thanks!